# Does ES5 modules accelate webpack build time comparing with ES6 modules?

Tags: build, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In convention, when we write a ES6 modules, we put source code in `src` folder, and compile it using `babel-loader` and `webpack` to `lib` or `dist` folder to set code to ES5, and set `main` entry to `dist` folder, then publish to npm.

> On the one hand, user can use this module without using webpack, and the code can run. On the other hand, when using webpack, ES5 code may reduce `babel-loader` time because it's already ES5 code.

What I confused is the second point, when using webpack, does ES5 codes in `node_module` reduce `babel-loader` time so we can accelate webpack build performance ?

The question is almost about ES5 npm modules with webpack build performance, although it's a convention we already did, I just want to know about something about webpack build performance. Thanks!

Comment: If code is already ES5 and doesn't have to be converted from ES6 to ES5, then it seems logical that performance would be better since it doesn't have to be converted. However, the code still needs to be parsed and traversed (I guess) so whether the performance difference has any significance depends on your concrete situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generally public packages are distributed with sources that have already been transformed. The performance benefit, with regards to Webpack and `babel-loader`, is that you can consume these sources as-is without having to process them  with `babel-loader`, so you'll commonly see:

```
{
    test: '\.js$',
    loader: 'babel',
    exclude: ['node_modules']
}
```

So, I too am confused about this excerpt, specifically why one would want to parse ES5 code with Babel, since no transformation would eventually take place.

Either way, the sources are always parsed by Webpack and not having to parse, transform them beforehand with `babel-loader` should improve performances.